# Conserved quantity in Noethers theorem with the use of a Killing vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, conservation-laws, vector-fields, geodesics

Consider a system given by the action:

$$S = \int  \sum_{i,j} G_{ij}(q) \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j dt$$

Now, consider the quantity $Q_v =  \sum_{i,j} G_{ij} v^i \dot{q}^j $ with $v^i$ the Killing vector.

I want to show that $Q_v$ is conserved so that $\frac{dQ_v}{dt} = 0 $.

How can one show this by using this relation of the Killing vector:
$$\sum_{i} (\partial_i G_{jk} v^i +  G_{ij} \partial_k v^i + G_{ki} \partial_j v^i) = 0 ~?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bland plugin, provided you recall to use the E-L equations of motion, which you skipped, $\frac{d}{dt} (2G_{ij}\dot{q} ^i)= \partial_j G_{ik} \dot q ^i \dot q ^k $. I'm using repeated index summation convation and utilizing the index-symmetry of the relevant metric.

The Killing symmetry condition then yields 
$$
\dot q ^i \dot q ^k (\partial_j G_{ik} v^j +  2G_{ij} \partial_k v^j)
 = 0 .
$$

It thus follows that the Killing symmetry  charge is conserved,
$$\frac{dQ_v}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\!(G_{ij}\dot q ^i) ~~v^j + G_{ij}\dot q ^i \dot v ^j \\
= \tfrac{1}{2}  \partial_j G_{ik} \dot q ^i \dot q ^k v^j +  G_{ij}\dot q ^i \dot q ^k \partial_k   v ^j= 
\frac{\dot q ^i \dot q ^k}{2} (  \partial_j G_{ik}  v^j +  2G_{ij}  \partial_k   v ^j)
 = 0 ~.$$